# How to search id into array and club together in php

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

Ok I'm seriously stuck, I've been working on array merge by finding id from array .I want to find SubjectID from array if it found then merge both array and calulate actual hour in from time and to time(calculate timing in between). my array code..
Actual Array:

```
Array
(
    [eventlist] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [allDay] => false
                    [id] => {83AE8778-A604-46F1-94BE-A045F2A9B548}
                    [SubjectID] => 2
                    [RoomID] => 2
                    [FromTime] => 00:30
                    [ToTime] => 01:45
                    [PlottingType] => Research
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [allDay] => false
                    [id] => {2B1F7B32-6D44-4700-8C50-F030B94D41F6}
                    [RoomID] => 2
                    [FromTime] => 00:00
                    [ToTime] => 00:45
                    [PlottingType] => Research
                )

         [2] => Array
                (
                    [allDay] => false
                    [id] => {83AE8778-A604-46F1-94BE-A045F2A9B548}
                    [SubjectID] => 3
                    [RoomID] => 2
                    [FromTime] => 00:30
                    [ToTime] => 01:45
                    [PlottingType] => Admin
                )

        )

)

expected output:
Array
(
    [eventlist] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Time] => 01:15
                    [PlottingType] => Research
                )

         [2] => Array
                (
                    [Time] => 00:15
                    [PlottingType] => Admin
                )

        )

)
```

please suggest me appropriate solution..

Comment: Your array data and expected output data are inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should foreach through all of them

```
$array; // Your array
$new_array = array(); // Empty new array
$new_array['eventlist'] = array();
foreach($array['eventlist'] as $inner) {

    if(isset($inner['SubjectID']) {
        // Work out your maths for time difference and put it into $interval
        $fromtime = new DateTime($inner['FromTime']);
        $totime   = new DateTime($inner['ToTime']);

        $interval = $fromtime->diff($totime);
        $interval = $interval->format('%H:%i');

        $new_inner = array(
            "Time" => $interval,
            "PlottingType" => $inner['PlottingType']
        );
        array_push($new_array['eventlist'], $new_inner);
    }

}
```

While untested. This SHOULD work with `PHP 5.4+`

Comment: He does not only want to calculate the diff of both times, but also want to add all the times with the same PlottingType.

Comment: That's not what he stated at all. That said, please format your dirty code to a decent standard.

Comment: Yeah after reviewing his code. My code outputs what he asked for, yours doesn't. And  your code burned my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

This was my try on the problem.
It keeps the keys like in your example.

```
$newarr = array();
$map = array();

foreach ($arr['eventlist'] as $key=>$val) 
{
  if (!isset($map[$val['PlottingType']]))
    $map[$val['PlottingType']] = $key;

  $fromTime = new DateTime($val['FromTime']);
  $toTime = new DateTime($val['ToTime']);
  $diff = $fromTime->diff($toTime);

  $type = $val['PlottingType'];

  if (!isset($newarr[$map[$val['PlottingType']]])) 
  {
    $newarr[$map[$val['PlottingType']]] = array(
      'time'=>$diff->format("%H:%i"),
      'PlottingType'=>$type
    );
  }
  else 
  {
    $oldtime = new DateTime($newarr[$map[$val['PlottingType']]]['time']);
    $newtime = $oldtime->add($diff);
    $newarr[$map[$val['PlottingType']]]['time'] = $newtime->format("H:i");
  }
}
```

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [time] => 01:30
            [PlottingType] => Research
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [time] => 01:30
            [PlottingType] => admin
        )
) if my array like this it club into one array and return into one singel array not give seperate plottingtype array. i want seperate array index not club .if plotting type diffrent then return different array.